# querySelector vs. querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have some trouble in creating a selector in javascript.
This is my code:

```
function __(selector){

    var self = {};
    self.selector = selector;

    if(typeof selector == 'object'){
       self.element = self.selector;
    }else{
       self.element = document.querySelector(self.selector);
    }

   // make a .css method to an element
    self.css = function(propval){
       return Object.assign(self.element.style,propval);
    }

   return self;
}
```

And my html file

```
<script src="js/selector.js"></script>
<script>
     window.onload = function(){
      __('p').css({'color':'red'});
    }
</script>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
<p>John</p>
```

The code above will only apply the `.css method` in the first `<p>` element. It's because I only used `querySelector`. Because `querySelector` only selects the first element found. And `querySelectorAll` selects all elements found. But when I try to change my selector to `querySelectorAll` It doesnt work for me anymore.

Comment: I posted an answer having a poyfill for `Object.assign`, as it doesn't work on IE11 and lower ... and I think we can't drop IE11 just yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the reason is `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList of the selected elements and **assigning CSS to a NodeList** wouldn't make much of an effect

That said, essentially you need a way to handle the case of a single element and a many in the same way

From the top of my head, a simple solution could be to always use *an arrays or the NodeList* and `forEach()` over them since both implement this method, like so:

```
function __(selector){

    var self = {};
    self.selector = selector;

    if(typeof selector == 'object'){
       self.elements = [self.selector];
    }else{
       self.elements = document.querySelectorAll(self.selector);
    }

    // make a .css method to an element
    self.css = function(propval){
       self.elements.forEach(function(element){
         Object.assign(element.style, propval);
       });
    }

   return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir,it works for me. By the way, you said that i should not use `Object.assign`? What should I replace ?

Comment: I'm glad it works! Regarding `Object.assign` **I was wrong** since apparently the compatibility got way better lately, so use it freely if you don't mind not being able to target IE [(source)](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Object_static_methods_Object.assign). I'll delete that part of my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here so this can probably be optimized, but with an array/list of objects you need to loop through each one

*Updated with [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) so this one work on at least IE11/10/9*

```js
function __(selector){

    var self = {};
    self.selector = selector;

    if(typeof selector == 'object'){
       self.element = self.selector;
    }else{
       self.elements = document.querySelectorAll(self.selector);
    }

   // make a .css method to an element
    self.css = function(propval){
       if (self.elements) {
         for (var i = 0; i < self.elements.length; i++) {
           Object.assign(self.elements[i].style,propval);
         }
         return;
       } else {
         Object.assign(self.element.style,propval);
       }
    }

   return self;
}

if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function (target, varArgs) { // .length of function is 2
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    var to = Object(target);

    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var nextSource = arguments[index];

      if (nextSource != null) { // Skip over if undefined or null
        for (var nextKey in nextSource) {
          // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource, nextKey)) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return to;
  };
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>
<p>John</p>
<div>Albert</div>
<script>
     window.onload = function(){
      __('p').css({'color':'red'});
      __(document.querySelector('div')).css({'color':'blue'});
    }
</script>
```